# Forms authentication and anonymous users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using forms authentication to keep track of users for a chat room application I'm creating. I have connected to my DB using `SqlMembershipProvider` that stores usernames and account information. When the user comes to the first page, they may enter a username and click a button to proceed to a room without using my `Login` control or my `CreateUserWizard`. I'd like to know how to create a temporary user thru code so they may use the service. I'm guessing `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser(...);` ? I've looked at that but don't know what to put for `providerUserKey`

Comment: What is "Windows Forms Authentication"? I think you're conflating "Windows Forms" (which has nothing to do with ASP.NET) and "Forms Authentication".

Comment: what do you mean by temporary user? like a test account? or do you want to write a client application or unit test that logs in

Comment: A temporary user is anyone that does not login or create a new user, only enters a username and uses my app without account credentials. These users would be deleted from DB upon logging out or exiting, but I still need to know who they are by username so they may post messages. It's a chat room, so an example would be: `tempUser007: hello everyone!` I would need to insert "tempUser007" into my DB without password, email, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `Membership.CreateUser(string, string)`.

[CreateUser on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8t4h2es(v=vs.110).aspx)

This call will allow you to add a User to the membership database with just the username and password.  You can use a `Guid` as the password for temp users if you'd like.

`providerUserKey` translates to "userid".  You can make that `Guid` as well, but I do not think you need it.  The `MembershipProvider` should facilitate the key generation based on the underlying table structure of the `Members` table.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/788206.aspx?CreateUser%20Method%20in%20MembershipProvider) link you can pass null to the `providerUserKey` attribute. Or you can generate your own value but you have to make sure it is unique. To do so you can use the GUID class to create unique identifiers for you.